# Short story about genetically modified/designer boy with behavioral problems and robot/android guardian

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I vaguely recall the parents chose too many traits (smart, attractive, etc.) for their genetically modified designer baby boy which they were warned could cause behavioral issues.  The parents get him an android/robot guardian. Parents were also arguing a lot in the story.  One of the arguments was about the designer traits they chose and the resulting behavior issues.

The android/robot guardian was a main character.  I can't remember other plot details.  I think they get in a fight with some other kids and the robot/android teaches the boy empathy.

I was read this story in the early 1990s in elementary school.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  (Was it online, in an anthology or a magazine?)  Does the guardian play a role in the plot, or is it just a detail?  What were the parents arguing about?  The boy, the robot, money, their jobs...  What was the final outcome?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Dinjer - It appears you're now using a different account than the one you used to post this question, which means you can no longer edit the question, leave comments beneath it, or mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can regain the ability to do all these things by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds a lot like the movie AI Artificial Intelligence, I googled to see if it was based on another story and it was based off of "1969 short story "Supertoys Last All Summer Long" by Brian Aldiss."

He wrote lots of scifi stories and maybe the one you are speaking of

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you identify the elements of the story that match the question?  The parents fighting, the mechanical guardian?

Comment: Supertoys Last All Summer Long isn't anything like this story.